# Python function passing parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to write a simple function that will give me a count of unique values from a specific column in pandas df. I would like to use the column name as the function parameter. However,the parameter does not get recognized as string inside the function.

Here is what I am trying to convert to a function where **c_type** is a **column name**.

```
c_type_count = data.groupby('c_type').c_type.count()
```

Here is the function. I use parameter column to pass the column name:

```
def uniques(column):
    count = data.groupby(column).column.count()
    print(count)
```

The **groupby(column)** part works as indented but the second reference **.column** stays as .column and I get an error because there is no column by that name in the df.

I understand what is happening there but since I am new to Python I don't necessarily know who to switch the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're simply looking for [`value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)

```
data['c_type'].value_counts()
```

Gives exactly what you describe you're looking for.

**Example**:

```
>>> data
  b_type c_type
0      d      b
1      d      a
2      d      a
3      c      a
4      c      a
5      d      b
6      c      a
7      d      b
8      c      b
9      c      a

>>> data['c_type'].value_counts()
a    6
b    4
```

**How to fix your custom function**

If you want to keep using your custom function, you just have to use standard indexing rather than attribute indexing, in other words, use square brackets instead of the dot notation to access your column. See the [documentation on indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) for more info

```
def uniques(column):
    count = data.groupby(column)[column].count()
    # Alternatively:
    # count = data.groupby(column).size()
    print(count)
```

This works as you want:

```
>>> uniques('c_type')
c_type
a    6
b    4
```

Comment: Thank you. I am curious to know though how I can make sure that the parameter gets picked as string for .column. Is there a different syntax that i need to use?

Comment: Awesome Thank you again.

Comment: You can using size , rather than count here

Comment: @Wen, true, I'll add that. Is there an advantage to `size` in this case, though?

Comment: Then you can just `data.groupby(column).size()`

Answer (score 1):

This is by design, in your example you are calling the `column` method of the GroupBy object, python never looks for column value in the current scope.
What you are looking for is the built-in function `getattr()` which will get an object attribute/method by its string name.

```
def uniques(column):
    count = getattr(data.groupby(column), column).count()
    print(count)
```

Comment: With a Pandas dataframe, the columns are dict items. They're _also_ available as attribute names as a convenience, when they happen to be valid identifier names and don't conflict with standard attributes, but that doesn't mean you should look them up as attributes rather than indices when you don't need that convenience. In other words, don't do `getattr(df, colname)`; just do `df[colname]`.